# Applying pixel to a mask

Tags: c#, image, processing, mask, digital

Im currently adding different features to a very simple digital image processing program. It is coded using the unsafe methods.
This program only works with greyscale images.

My question is how do i apply masks to pixels?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry about that. Google search habbit.

Comment: Actually, the [so] platform makes the tags searchable, so you don't need to worry about mangling your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just multiply pix_vals by the mask and sum. So just add:

p[y * stride + x] = pix_val[0] * Gx[0] + ... + pix_val[8] * Gx[8];

EDIT: Watch out for the corner cases though, you should really change your offsets to [-1, 0, 1] instead of [0, 1, 2] and handle the boundary conditions.

Comment: Perfect. Thats all i was looking for.